# Insert elements into 2D array with given start position and interval in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, intervals

Example:

```
NSArray *arr = ... //[[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]]
NSIndex startPosition = 1;
NSIndex interval = 3;
NSArray *result = ... //[[1,a,2,3,a], [4,5,a], [6,7,a,8]]
```

Where `a` - some values (can be different).

if it is 1D array then the task is simple - I just insert after each N elements starting from a given position. But how to deal with it when I have 2D array?

**Updated**

> How does it related to iOS?

Mobup SDK, manual inserting of native ads. The answer will help to find positions to insert ads into table with multiple sections.

**Updated**

`startPosition` - first index to insert

`interval` - skip N elements before index to insert

If it was 1D array then indexes to insert are:

startPosition, startPosition + interval, startPosition + interval * 2, ...

But it is 2D array and it is hard to describe formula for it - look at example.

Comment: what is start position and what is interval in your context?

Comment: If you want to add some values to an Array in Objective-C then your array should be mutable

Comment: They are integer values, startPosition >=0, interval >= 1. Task - to insert items into 2D array with interval like in 1D array (but involving the second dimension).

Comment: @ReinierMelian mutable array is somewhere behind dots. Initial values and the final result are usually immutable.

Comment: To insert an object in two dimensional array you need two indexs

Comment: @MartinR updated. Your question about relation to Swift is offtop and should be reported

Comment: I asked because you post Objective-C code and tag the question with [swift]. How is that "offtop" and why should it be "reported"?

Comment: @ReinierMelian of course I need 2 indexes. And I need somehow translate `startPosition` and `interval` into set of pairs of these indexes

Comment: @MartinR swift code can be simply imported into objective-c and vice versa. So both languages are applicable.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov here we going again, in my first comment I asked about the meaning of this two values `interval` and `position`

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov: Good to know, thank you  for telling me!

Comment: @MartinR edited again. I hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state you know how to solve this if the array is 1D. In pseudo-code you will be using something like:

```
currentIndex = startPosition
while currentIndex < arr.length do
   insert item
   advance currentIndex by interval
end
```

To extend this to a 2D array (array of arrays) you just need to nest the above in a loop over the arrays, something like:

```
currentIndex = startPosition
for arr in arrayOfArrays
   while currentIndex < arr.length do
      insert item
      advance currentIndex by interval
   end
   // at this point currentIndex has passed the array, to determine
   // first index into next array simply subtract the length of the
   // current array
   currentIndex -= arr.length
end
```

HTH